# My custom metabox show for all post type or page

Tags: wordpress

I have create a custom post type 'product' and also add some meta boxes. When i add page, post, menu and any post type my meta boxes are show every where at the top of page. I want to show only product post type.

The code is here.

> post type is product

```
function marbel_product_meta_fields() 
{
    add_meta_box( 'product_meta_box',
    'product Details',
    'display_product_meta_box',
    'product', 'normal', 'high'
    );
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'marbel_product_meta_fields' );

function display_product_meta_box( $product) 
    {
        $price = get_post_meta( $product->ID, 'product_price', true ); 
        $proVari = get_post_meta( $product->ID, 'product_variant', true );  
        echo '<p class="product-price"> Product Price </p>'; 
        echo '<input type="text" name="product_price" placeholder="product price" value="'.$price.'" />';
        echo '<p class="product-price"><b> Product Variant </b></p>';  

               $varipro = explode('*',$proVari);
                    foreach( $varipro as $pv )
                    {   ?>
                        <div class="product-variant">                       
                        <input type="checkbox" name="deal_index[]" class="left-check" />
                        <input type="text" name="product_variant[]" value="<?php echo $pv; ?>" placeholder="Varient title" size="30%">
                        <input type="text" name="variant_price" placeholder="Varient price" value="" size="30%"> </div>
                    <?php  }    ?>
                    </br>
                    <input class="addmore button-primary" type="button" name="add_variant" value="Add Variant" onClick="addMoreVariant();" />
                    <input class="deleterow button-primary" type="button" name="del_variant" value="Delete" onClick="deleteRowVariant();" />
    <?php }
add_action( 'save_post', 'display_product_meta_box');

function add_product_fields( $productid, $product ) 
{
    if ( $product->post_type == 'product' ) 
    {
        if ( isset( $_POST['product_price'] ) && $_POST['product_price'] != '' ) 
        {
            update_post_meta( $productid, 'product_price', $_POST['product_price'] );  
        }

        if ( isset( $_POST['product_variant'] ) && $_POST['product_variant'] != '' ) 
        { 
            $productVariant =implode('*',$_POST['product_variant']);
            update_post_meta( $productid, 'product_variant', $productVariant); 
        }   
    }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'add_product_fields', 10, 2 );
```

Please check where i am wrong.
Please help me.

Comment: try to remove : add_action( 'save_post', 'display_product_meta_box') and replace action 'admin_init' into 'add_meta_boxes'

Comment: Many Many thanks to you Brejesh.
Its working now by removing add_action( 'save_post', 'display_product_meta_box')

Comment: I am glad it works for you @husain

Comment: Thanks Again Vrajesh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this Hook `add_action( 'save_post', 'display_product_meta_box')` This will definitely work!

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

change action 'init' into 'add_meta_boxes'.

Change below :

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'marbel_product_meta_fields' );
```

Replace with :

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'marbel_product_meta_fields' );
```

Comment: Thanks vrajesh,
I have check your suggestion but problem is still there

Answer (score 1):

> For showing your Meta box to all the post type you can iterate the post types through the loop structure using foreach loop.

Have a try like this and it will work for you .

```
foreach ( array( 'post', 'page', 'custom_whatever', 'whatever2' ) as $page )
    add_meta_box( 'id', 'whatever', $callback, $page, $context, $priority, $callback_args );
```

Comment: Hello Naresh i got my answer.
my code is running after deleted this line
add_action( 'admin_init', 'marbel_product_meta_fields' );

Answer (score 0):

There is one solution you can use almost anywhere. First you need to made function to find post type anywhere in the WordPress:

```
function marbel_get_post_type ($find = false) {
        global $post, $parent_file, $typenow, $current_screen, $pagenow;
        
        $post_type = NULL;
        
        if($post && (property_exists($post, 'post_type') || method_exists($post, 'post_type')))
            $post_type = $post->post_type;

        if(empty($post_type) && !empty($current_screen) && (property_exists($current_screen, 'post_type') || method_exists($current_screen, 'post_type')) && !empty($current_screen->post_type))
            $post_type = $current_screen->post_type;

        if(empty($post_type) && !empty($typenow))
            $post_type = $typenow;

        if(empty($post_type) && function_exists('get_current_screen'))
            $post_type = get_current_screen();

        if(empty($post_type) && isset($_REQUEST['post']) && !empty($_REQUEST['post']) && function_exists('get_post_type') && $get_post_type = get_post_type((int)$_REQUEST['post']))
            $post_type = $get_post_type;

        if(empty($post_type) && isset($_REQUEST['post_type']) && !empty($_REQUEST['post_type']))
            $post_type = sanitize_key($_REQUEST['post_type']);

        if(empty($post_type) && in_array($pagenow, array('edit.php', 'post-new.php')))
            $post_type = 'post';

        if(is_array($find))
        {
            return in_array($post_type, $find, true);
        }
        else if(is_string($find))
        {
            return ($post_type === $find);
        }
        
        $post_type = apply_filters( 'btnr_get_post_type', $post_type);
        
        return $post_type;
    }
```

And after that just you can do this:

```
function marbel_product_meta_fields() 
{
    if( marbel_get_post_type('product') ) return;
    /* 
        You can now add metaboxes here 
    */
}
```

...or like this

```
function marbel_product_meta_fields() 
{
    if( marbel_get_post_type() == 'product' ) return;
    /* 
        You can now add metaboxes here 
    */
}
```

The function I give you is my peace of art and you can use it anywhere for any work you want.